# Declare charset for a (e.g. php) file not containing special characters

Tags: php

I am searching for a way to specify the charset of a file, e.h. a PHP file, which does NOT contain special characters.

Linux' file command does recognize them as ISO-8859-1*.

Is there a way without adding useless comments like

```
// Treat this as UTF-8 öüä
```

Like CSS'

```
@charset "utf-8";
```

Thanks :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
ini_set('default_charset', 'iso-8895-15');
```

Make sure to write this in all your "root" PHP files. Alternatively you can use the header method of PHP to set the charset explicitly:

```
header('Content-type', 'text/html; charset=iso-8859-1');
```

Or follow these instructions:
http://mindspill.net/computing/linux-notes/determine-and-change-file-character-encoding/

**References:**

[1] https://help.fortrabbit.com/encoding

Comment: I did not mean what is passed in http headers. I mean the raw file on disk so that a "file foo.php" does recognize it as utf-8.

Comment: Oh ok, than I missunderstood your question. these are settings you have to set during writing in your notepad, IDE or whatever you're using.

Comment: It hast nothing todo with the IDE. As long as there is no special character, linux' file command will see it as ASCII. My question is if there is a common code "block" to be used for declaring it as UTF-8 so that file and most IDEs will see it as UTF-8 file.